# Account Inactive Page Not Working in django-allauth

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-allauth

I have successfully setup an authentication system with django application using the popular django-allauth package. I suspended a registered user by updating `SuspendedUser.is_active=False` but whenever I try to login as the suspended user I'd get the failed authentication message `The username and/or password you specified are not correct.`.
Do I need any special configuration to display the `account_inactive.html` template as I cannot find anything that mentions that in the official documentation?.

**Note:** django-allauth version is 0.49.0 and django version is 4.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing my configurations, I realized I was using a custom authentication backend in my `settings.py` file. django-allauth requires `allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend` to handle authentication and permissions.

Adding this to my project config solved the problem

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
   
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
   
]
```

Although it was stated in the [docs](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can override log-in function of django-allauth. And you can create a dield under your user model names `is_suspended` instead of giving `is_active=False`. And in login function before login() put an if statement.

```
#in django-allauth login function

if request.user.is_suspended:
    message(request,'You have suspended! Cannot login!')
    return
```

render(request, 'user/user_policy.html' {'message':message})

or search [django-alluth signals](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html)

```
#in User model:

class User(models.Model):
     ...
     ...
     ...
     is_suspended = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: As far as I know, `django.contrib.auth.models.User` doesn't have `is_suspended` attribute, could you please link a doc

Comment: You need to add yourself  under to the User Model